# Is this line- 'The less genuine the windows is, the better it is' correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

Can anyone tell me, is this line correct or not?

"The less genuine the windows is, the better it is"

Comment: It is certainly ungrammatical; and even if it were corrected (is >> are) it wouldn't mean anything I can discern.

Comment: By any chance do you mean Windows OS?

Comment: yes, windows os

Comment: If you're referring to the OS, then the above sentence is correct. We can argue about the meaning though, because I prefer my Windows original. :)

Comment: Btw, to be more succinct, I think you can go with `The less genuine the Windows is, the better.`

Comment: If you're referring to the OS, "Windows" should be capitalized to show that it is a proper name. Otherwise it looks like you're talking about "windows" in the conventional sense, holes in the wall with glass in them. In that case "windows" is plural and you have improper subject/verb agreement.

Comment: The above sentence is not correct.  No one calls Windows, "the windows".  Simply removing the word "the" and capitalizing the word "windows" will fix your sentence.  "The less genuine Windows is, the better [it is]."  Everyone knows the proper name Windows refers to the OS.  "The widows" will make the reader think about the windows in their home, as in, "I think the windows are better when they are not genuine."

Answer (score 1):

As @AmirSyafrudin said, if you're referring to Windows as an operating system, the sentence is correct as long as you capitalize "windows" (making it a singular noun).

In fact, you could even say "The less genuine the Windows is, the better".

Comment: Your answer corrects an error in the original post.  Changing the capitalization of "Windows" changes the meaning of the sentence -- and changes whether the sentence is grammatical.